# This system has solution or not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, systems-of-equations

I am working the next set of lineal equations

$\begin{cases}
7x+2y=1 & 1\\
21x+6y=3 & 2
\end{cases}$
So multiplying (1) by -3

$7x+2y=1(-3)$

$-21x-6y=-3$

Adding both equations

$21x+6y=3$

$-21x-6y=-3$

0x+0y=0

0=0

This seems to be a uncompatible/no solutions system, but graphically the system is
[image]
So there is a common point in (0,1/2),then it would have ,at least, one solution.
And this solution solve the equations:
$\begin{cases}
7(0)+2\frac{1}{2}=1 & \\
21(0)+6\frac{1}{2}=3 & 
\end{cases}$
but I have tested the system using the usual methods and gives the $\emptyset$.
Then this system has solution or not?

**UPDATE**
The graphs are wrong the right one is
[image]
so it has infinite solutions.

Comment: The graphs are not correct. You may want to check again.

Comment: Im checking it...

Comment: You say that "This seems to be a uncompatible/no solutions system". Nope. Because, $$7x+2y=1\iff 21x+6y=3$$ This means, we have infinitely many solutions and this is enough to solve $7x+2y=1\implies y=\frac{1-7x}{2}$

Comment: These are coincident lines because the ratios of corresponding coefficients are equal.

Comment: A system of equations will have infinitely many solutions if one equation is a scalar multiple of another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have either graphed $-7x+2y=1$ or $-21x+6y=3$ by mistake instead of the equations given in your system. In your original system, equation 2 is simply $3$ times equation 1. As such, you have two unknowns but only one relation between them, so your system has infinite solutions.

Answer (score 5):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 2 \\ 21 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$ is a rank 1 matrix i.e. it's not full-ranked.
So it's not invertible.

Answer (score 4):

The system has infinitely many solutions because
$$7x+2y=1\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad 21x+6y=3,$$
so for any $x$ you can take $y=\frac{1-2y}{7}$ to get a solution.